# Embed favicon using a userscript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, userscripts

I have a tiny script designed to change the favicon on Google Music from the Play Store icon to something actually recognizable as Music related:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Update Google Music Favicon
// @version        1.0
// @description    Replaces Google Music icon with something almost like the old one but much uglier.
// @include        http://play.google.com/music/*
// @include        https://play.google.com/music/*
// ==/UserScript==

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    a=document.createElement("link");
    a.setAttribute("type", "image/jpeg");
    a.setAttribute("rel", "icon");
    a.setAttribute("href","data:image/jpeg;base64,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");
    document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(a);
}, false);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, even if I enter it in the JS console. I've tried replacing it with the Stack Overflow favicon URL and that did not work either, but switching it to the google.com/favicon.ico worked - I'm guessing the issue is the favicon isn't coming from the same domain? Is there a way around this? I don't see anything useful in the debugging console.

The URL I'm connecting to is:
https://play.google.com/music/listen?u=0#/now

Comment: try adding an attribute `type=image/jpeg`

Comment: Doesn't seem to have helped :(

Comment: This works fine on both FF and Chrome, although you should use `a.setAttribute("rel", "shortcut icon");`.  What are your all your relevant specs?  Download and install [this script](http://pastebin.com/f9vxUMZS).  With that script installed, do you see the "\*\*\*" messages in the console?  If not, on what *exact* URL?

Comment: The URL I'm connecting to is: https://play.google.com/music/listen?u=0#/now. I'm testing in Chrome 27.0.1453.93 on OS X. My handler definitely fires (I see console printouts if I add them), the icon just doesn't change.

Comment: I removed the window event listener and just did a 15s timeout before executing and _still_ does not work.

Comment: Well, it works on Windows with latest Chrome release (27.0.1453.94 m). Can't test on OS X, but there may be different cross-origin and `data:` URI permissions/handling for that OS+browser. There also might be an extension option or a  `chrome://flags/` setting for that, maybe. ... Otherwise, try the code in Firefox.

Comment: Do you see the added `<link>` in the page's HTML?  If so, use the debug tools to delete the preceding `<link>` nodes.

Comment: Damn, it works perfectly in Firefox 21 (though I couldn't figure out how to install the script and converted it to a Firefox extension, it then worked fine).

Comment: Also, no, the added link didn't show up in the page source in Chrome

Comment: Well, then, if you try the code from the Chrome console (minus the event handler), doesn't it give an error message?  This may be a faulty installation on your machine, or a Chrome bug on OS X.  ... PS: On FF, you'd install the Greasemonkey extension and then the script installs as-is. But making an extension works too. ;-)

Comment: Also, on Windows, Chrome 27 introduced some user-scripting bugs (not this one at last check).  You might try reverting to Chrome 26.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An old question but I hope to help somebody

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Update Google Music Favicon
// @version        1.0
// @description    Replaces Google Music icon with something almost like the old one but much uglier.
// @include        http://play.google.com/music/*
// @include        https://play.google.com/music/*
// ==/UserScript==
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var favicon = document.querySelector('link[rel~="icon"]');
    var clone = favicon.cloneNode(!0);
    clone.href = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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";
    favicon.parentNode.removeChild(favicon);
    document.head.appendChild(clone);
}, false);
```

the code is quite simple, we take the element, clone it, change the href attribute of the clone then we remove the original element and add the new element that we cloned

Comment: I came here to make a script to change Github's favicon, because it is invisible on a black background of my dark theme in Firefox. So I just used your code directly and what a surprise when I realize that the Google Music favicon is actually an excellent match for the GitHub favicon, which looks like headphones anyway! :-)